# JDBC - two WHERE clause

Tags: where-clause

How I can write a JDBC request with two WHERE clauses.
When I only one WHERE cluse the request is fine.

```
// example of array
String[] listeId1 = null;
listeId1[0]  =['0'];
listeId1[1]  =['1'];
String[] listeId = null;
listeId[0] = ['00']
listeId[1] = ['01']
//I don't know how many elements there will be in listeId1 and listeId  
String inClause = "?";
    int i = 1;
    while (i <= listeId.length - 1 ) {
        inClause += ",?";
        i++;
    } 


//my request
List<Map<String, Object>> result = this.getJdbcTemplate()
                .queryForList("SELECT * FROM TABLE_FONCTION " +
                        "WHERE ROLE_ID IN (" + inClause + ")" , listeId
                        + " AND PROCESSUS_ID IN (" + inClause1 + ")" ,listeId1 )
                        ; 



// Definition of my table
CREATE TABLE TABLE_FONCTION (
  FONCTION_ID       NUMBER(18)   NOT NULL,
  ACTIVE            CHAR(1)      NOT NULL,
  TYPE_FONCTION_ID  NUMBER(18)   NOT NULL,
  PROCESSUS_ID  NUMBER(18)   NOT NULL,
  ROLE_ID       NUMBER(18)   NOT NULL
);
```

What's wrong with my request ?

Comment: How does one assign to elements of a non-existant array?

Answer (score 0):

You never defined `inClause1`; in particular, before using it to build your query.

Comment: It's just because I don't write all the code my Jvav class but inClause1 is defined before.

Comment: @Laetitia28: Then maybe you defined it incorrectly; without seeing it, one cannot say.